# Iniciar uma thread novamente

Tags: java, thread

Tenho um evento no botão iniciar, sempre que carrego são geradas 3 threads que iniciam a contagem de 30 ate 0, a que chegar 1º ao 0 ganha. Mas contudo volto a carregar umas vezes no botão iniciar e a contagem começa em 30 e faz tudo igual, se continuar a carregar no botão iniciar mais uma ou duas vezes ele vai erros e deixa de correr a thread. 
A minha questão é: Eu inicio três threads quando carrego no botão iniciar mas para voltar a fazer isso na mesma frame é preciso matar as threads ou interrompe las?

c1,c2,c3 são objetos Cavalo.

- Classe CorridaCavalos

  ```
  iniciar.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          c1.setMovimentos(30);
          c2.setMovimentos(30);
          c3.setMovimentos(30);

          c1.start();         //start iniciar o run da thread cavalo c1 - classe cavalo
          c2.start();
          c3.start();
      }


  });
  ```
- Classe Cavalo extends thread - onde defino instruções da mesma

  ```
  @Override
  public void run(){
  try {
      while(movimentos > 0){
          sleep((long) (500*Math.random()));
          movimentos--;
          textField.setText(Integer.toString(movimentos));        //Converter Inteiro para String
      }
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      interrupt();
  }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é preciso finalizar as threads. Mais do que isso, você deve declarar suas instâncias de Cavalo dentro de `actionPerformed()`, para que a cada clique sejam criadas e  colocadas em execução novas threads:

```
iniciar.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (c1 != null) {
            c1.setMovimentos(0);
            c1.interrupt();
            c2.setMovimentos(0);
            c2.interrupt();
            c3.setMovimentos(0);
            c3.interrupt();
        }
        c1 = new Cavalo();
        c2 = new Cavalo();
        c3 = new Cavalo();

        c1.setMovimentos(30);
        c2.setMovimentos(30);
        c3.setMovimentos(30);

        c1.start();         //start iniciar o run da thread cavalo c1 - classe cavalo
        c2.start();
        c3.start();
    }


});
```

Observação: o comando `interrupt()` abaixo do `catch` é desnecessário.

Comment: porque é que o interrupt() é desnecessário?

Comment: Porque quando a `InterruptedException` é lançada a thread já está interrompida. Não é necessário interrompê-la novamente. Basta os `interrupt()` chamados dentro de `actionPerformed()`, que são os que causam o lançamento da `InterruptedException`.

Comment: Na verdade também esses `interrupted()` podem não ser suficientes. Acrescentei o comportamento de zerar os movimentos, o que faz as threads saírem dos loops, para os casos em que o `interrupted()` é chamado e a thread não se encontra em `sleep()`.